# Why do I get GET requests on my POST request handlers

Tags: jquery, http, browser

My webapp makes several AJAX requests to my web server. Most of them are POST requests - done using jQuery's `$.post` or `$.ajax(type:'POST',..)`. Since my webapp is the only client of these endpoints, I've not implemented GET handlers seeing no reason why the server should receive GET requests if my app is not making them.

Many times however I do see GET requests for these endpoints in my server logs. Since I don't implement them, they fail with response code 405. This doesn't happen frequently, but it's not very rare either.

My question is, do any browsers/firewalls/proxies automatically convert POST requests to GET?

Comment: I can't be sure but I would imagine that would go against every definition of the HTTP spec

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing some web crawler hitting that url and not realizing it's only for POSTs and not GETs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

What you are seeing are likely bots, crawling the web.  This is very normal.